# Where has the .themes folder gone?

Tags: 13.04, themes, directory

I'm now running 13.04 and wanted to install some of my favourite themes, but found that the folder .themes was just missing. Does it work to just make the folder?

Comment: That folder is never created by default the user has to create it.

Comment: Same for `~/.icons`.

Comment: But up until now it was always there already!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes.

Create the folder `.themes` in your `$HOME` if you don't find one.

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: @UriHerrera The themes don't show on Gnome Tweak tool, Ubuntu Tweak or Unity Tweak Tool :(

Comment: Are you sure it's the correct folder structure?: ~/.themes/THEME/gtk-2.0, gtk-3.0, metacity, index.theme

Comment: @UriHerrera I just dragged the .tar.gz to .themes. It has always worked before.

Comment: Before? do you mean in Gnome 2?. In Gnome 3.x you have to extract the contents of the compressed files.

Comment: @UriHerrera In 12.10 - both unity.

Comment: I'm 100 % sure it has never worked this way.

Comment: @UriHerrera It has with me :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8849/discussion-between-madtux-and-uri-herrera)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
/usr/share/themes
```

at least thats where I found mine.

Hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install the themes in `/usr/share/themes`  but you need root. Or you can install them in `~/.themes` if that Dir doesn't exist them make it!  Also, make sure it is a folder not a file like .zip, .tar, .tar.gz, ect...