# Cannot boot ubuntu in recovery mode | Waiting for Network configuration

Tags: boot, networking, grub2

My ubuntu is stuck at the "**Waiting for network configuration error**". I have found a bunch of questions similar to this.

My error 
[Waiting for NW configuaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VSFp.png)

**Setup**: A guest Linux machine in VMware ESXi with 3 network adapters connected to various networks. I have just cloned it, therefore, it is not assigned any other IP address. DHCP enabled. This is the FIRST time i am booting. I am stuck in the configuration mode. I am supposed to enter the recovery mode and configure the network.

Everyone seems to solve this problem by entering terminal by recovery boot. However, my problem is that

1) I have **no root access**. I want to reboot in recovery mode but it does not give the option

[Recovery option does not appear in my ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGzOD.png)

2) I cannot enter CLI using ALT+CTRL+F2. I do not know why.

3) I tried changing the command line of the boot by adding 'rescue' as a command line argument. It did not work. Should I keep working in this direction?

4) I can try changing the /etc/network/interfaces from grub initramfs. Not sure how to edit the files.

I am kinda lost here about the actual cause of the problem and the direction to pick. Can anyone please help?

Comment: This answer worked, https://askubuntu.com/questions/326528/how-to-boot-to-the-recovery-mode-if-it-is-not-listed-in-grub

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where has the .themes folder gone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297865/where-has-the-themes-folder-gone)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to boot to the recovery mode if it is not listed in Grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326528/how-to-boot-to-the-recovery-mode-if-it-is-not-listed-in-grub)